# Leetcode is not signing in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My LeetCode Account is not accessible through VS Code. What should be the issue?
Please Help me to solve that.

[LeetCode + VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVqWT.jpg)

I tried linking the leetcode account to vscode but it failed many a times.
Please help me to link it.
Give me some solutions.